# Gulp bower image path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, bower

i have problem with settings gulp. I see this problem when i want to use plugin. Ie. add to install "juriejan/raty#bower-package-fix" and I **don't see images**.

I think path of source are bad (my settings..), because plugin wants image path 'star-half.png', but now is working only when i change this into '/images/star-half.png'.

In build.js i have:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var paths = gulp.paths;

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
  pattern: ['gulp-*', 'main-bower-files', 'uglify-save-license', 'del']
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
  return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles())
    .pipe($.filter('**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,bmp}'))
    .pipe($.flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/images/'));
});
gulp.task('build', ['html', 'images', 'fonts', 'misc']);
```

and in gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.paths = {
  src: 'src',
  dist: '../public',
  tmp: '.tmp',
  e2e: 'e2e'
};
```

bower install create image file in 'public/images/'

tree of project is

```
my-app   
  |-front
    |- bower.json
    |- package.json
  |- public
    |-images
```

i try sth like this, but steel not working:

```
gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.src + '/images/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/images/'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the demo included with `raty`

You can see here how they are declaring the path to the images:

```
$('#starHalf').raty({
  half     : true,
  path     : null,
  starHalf : 'demo/images/star-half-mono.png',
  starOff  : '../lib/images/star-off.png',
  starOn   : '../lib/images/star-on.png'
});
```

[`https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty/blob/master/demo/index.html#L3702`](http://%60https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty/blob/master/demo/index.html#L3702%60)

If you already are using gulp to copy the images to your `/images/` folder you can set the path to `/images/` or not alter the path and set the option for the images directly like the demo does above.

Comment: Then, my settings are correct or path should be '/assets/images/'? I asking, because, when I fighting with this, i have this strange path..

Comment: Where can you access the images when you build? That should be the path.

Comment: When i use command 'gulp serve:dist' from https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular#use-gulp-tasks. 
All packages create files in public. 
Ie. plugin 'Rate' create in images in public/images, another use fonts from public/fonts etc. 

When i change this path: 
gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.src + '/images/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/images/'));
});

It will change path for all images?

Comment: Gulp is already going through your bower files and copying the images to the `/public/images/` folder. There is no reason for you to change that gulp task. What you need to do is tell raty where those images are when you are serving your app.

Comment: Ok great :) I will check it. Tnx :)